# Using kendoDateTimePicker's value to update kendoGrid dataSource filter isn't working

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-datetimepicker, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo DateTime selector on a page, from which I take its value (instance of Date according to Kendo docs http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#methods-value), and then I'd like to insert it into a kendoGrid's dataSource filter.

The problem is, that it doesn't appear to be working... I've set up a demo here: there are 2x inputs, one for each column in the grid -  when you click the go button those inputs are applied as filters to the grid. The text filter works, but the datetimepicker doesn't...

http://jsfiddle.net/gUF43/6/

```
// This line sets the filters - the text one is populated and datetime isn't :(
$("#thegrid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter(filters);
```

At the end I'd expect the grid to show the populated filter when you click on it, but its empty which implies that it didn't like the date object.

What do you reckon? Thankyou.

Comment: Who cares what the `__proto__` property is? It has a date value and the date is usable as such, with all of the methods returning the correct value.

Comment: Updated jsFiddle - I'm only wondering about proto because its the only visible indicator at this point that its not working... Using Chrome 31.0.1650.63. I'm trying to the the datetimepicker value into grid filter and its failing silently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with your updated fiddle is very helpful. Working with my updated fiddle based on yours, if you update your input text to `Hello` and change the time picker to `10:30am` you will see the filter is now working properly.

The `field` property below was set incorrectly.

```
    var filter = {
      field: 'Timestamp',
      operator: 'eq',
      value: val
    };
```

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyze/gUF43/7/

Comment: OK, I don't understand why, but Chrome has decided to give me a valid object now... However, the value of datetimepicker still refuses to be inserted into the filter - any ideas? jsFiddle updated

Comment: @KatyaS I have updated my answer to reflect your updated Fiddle.

Comment: Neil, thank you very much for your time. I'm looking at your fiddle. When I click GO I can see that the filter is applied to the grid, but when I click on the filter it is empty - is this the case for you as well?

Comment: Yes, that is the case for me as well. I messed a round for a bit, but was unfortunately not able to get that bit resloved.

Comment: Well, based on your reply I have fixed my project code and it works correctly - it was pretty silly not to see that I was using the wrong field name :) I also don't understand why the fiddle code isn't working, but I'm going to leave it for now. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to new up the date like so: value: new Date().

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that - see commended out line in jsFiddle link - the result is the same :(

Comment: Hmmm... seems to work for me. I am testing in the latest Chrome however.

Comment: When you expand the element in the console, do you not see __proto__ = "Invalid Date" ?

Comment: Bah! Sorry, I was clicking on the prototype for the object, not the value property. So yeah, that change appears to not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you limited to 2012.2.710? I wouldnt be surprised its fixed in a newer version.

Comment: Updated jsFiddle... We're using the latest version of KendoUI - what do you reckon now? When clicking GO button, I'd expect the grid filter to be filled in...